# Fetching Data from Sqlite Database to TableLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Okay, so I'm working on this project for days and still trying to figure out what's wrong with my code.
Basically, I have a fragment class with button for searching the data based on the input from edittext on ReportFragment.java. It also contains TableLayout.

**ReportFragment.java**

```
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DBHandler db = new DBHandler(getActivity());

            SearchReport sc = new SearchReport();
```

> Get Text from TextView for searching purpose

```
            sc.setFrom(from.getText().toString());
            sc.setUntil(until.getText().toString());
            sc.setName(name.getText().toString());

            List<Registration> src = db.getList();

            for(Registration rg : src){

                String a = Integer.toString(rg.getID());
                String b = rg.getName();
                String c = rg.getTo();
                String d = rg.getNeed();
                String e = rg.getNumber();
                String f = rg.getAddress();
                String g = rg.getDate();
```

> I set the string to textview in TableLayout

```
                number.setText(a);
                name.setText(b);
                to.setText(c);
                need.setText(d);
                hp.setText(e);
                address.setText(f);
                d.setText(g);
            }
        }
    });
```

I store the values that inserted from ReportFragment thru global variable written inside **SearchReport.java** and store another values from another fragment in **Registration.java**

Now Another class is DBHandler which working as the Database Handler.

**DBHandler.java**

> Getting searchable Report

```
public List<Registration> getList(){
    SearchReport sc = new SearchReport();
    List<Registration> crReg = new ArrayList<Registration>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REGISTRATION + " WHERE " + DATE_COLUMN + " BETWEEN "
            + sc.getFrom() + " AND " + sc.getUntil() + " AND " + sc.getName();

    Log.d("Query", selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Registration reg = new Registration();
            reg.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            reg.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            reg.setTo(cursor.getString(2));
            reg.setNeed(cursor.getString(3));
            reg.setNumber(cursor.getString(4));
            reg.setAddress(cursor.getString(5));
            reg.setDate(cursor.getString(6));
            crReg.add(reg);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return crReg;
}
```

The looping went thru the **Registration.java** to see the values based on conditional query from report fragment.

I logged my query as u can see. But it returned the values as null.

```
04-05 11:34:33.150 28414-28414/? D/Query: SELECT  * FROM registrasi WHERE tanggal BETWEEN null AND null AND null
```

And this is my layout in case needed.

```
<TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/table_main_detail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:stretchColumns="*">
                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            >
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_column="0"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="No"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Nama"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_column="2"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Ketemu"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_column="3"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Tujuan"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_column="4"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Nomor HP"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_column="5"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Alamat"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_column="6"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Date"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            >
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/no_report"
                                android:layout_column="0"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="No"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/name_report"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Nama"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/to_report"
                                android:layout_column="2"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Nama"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/need_report"
                                android:layout_column="3"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Ketemu"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/number_report"
                                android:layout_column="4"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Name"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/address_report"
                                android:layout_column="5"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Name ASDK ASJDHAS ASJDH"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/date_report"
                                android:layout_column="6"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:layout_span="1"
                                android:text="Name"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: That is because you define a new SearchReport in getList() method which doesn't contains the values, Try to pass them with the method as a parameter

Comment: Obviously `SearchReport sc = new SearchReport();` will make all your fields be null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you try this

```
public List<Registration> getList(SearchReport sc) 
    List<Registration> crReg = new ArrayList<Registration>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REGISTRATION + " WHERE " + DATE_COLUMN + " BETWEEN "
        + sc.getFrom() + " AND " + sc.getUntil() + " AND " + sc.getName();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

Then

```
List<Registration> src = db.getList(sc) ;
```

Then read up on SQL injection and how your code is susceptible to it.